# 3rd Level Automapper Relationship

Tags: c#, linq, automapper

I'm integrating with a 3rd party API which is returning a complex data structure and in a part of it I have the following relationship.

```
    public class Parent{
    public List<SmartLink> SmartLink { get; set; }
    }
```

The `SmartLink` object looks like below:

```
public class SmartLink {
    public Address AddressInfo { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried to map it in several ways, one of them below, but I still get a null on the AddressInfo object.

```
 cfg.CreateMap<Address, AddressInfo>(); 
 cfg.CreateMap<Source, Parent>()   
     //This is not allowed since Automapper cannot map to 2nd level                 
     .ForMember(d => d.SmartLink.AddressInfo, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Smartlink.ToList().Select(addr => addr.Address)));
```

The line below works perfectly:

```
.ForMember(d => d.SmartLink, map => map.MapFrom(s => s.Smartlink.ToList()))
```

How can I map/flatten a 3rd level property with Automapper, any pointers?

Comment: You need ForPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had overthought on it. I simply added the following mapping and it worked.

```
cfg.CreateMap<Address, AddressInfo>();
cfg.CreateMap<SmartlinkPart, SmartLink>(MemberList.Destination)
                     .ForMember(d => d.AddressInfo, map => map.MapFrom(s => s.Address));
```

The idea is that for the member `AddressInfo`, the first line above will provide it's mapping instruction.